# PHP's file upload is failing on server

Tags: php, file-upload

I am developing a website that includes functions with file upload. This was working perfectly on localhost, but once I uploaded the site to my server it fails.

I have the following code to handle the file upload:

```
case "upload_to_gallery":

        /*******************************
         ****   UPLOAD TO GALLERY   ****
         *******************************/

        if ($con->checkLogin() && isset($_FILES['uploaded_files'])) {
            $gallery_name = $_POST['gallery_name'];

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['uploaded_files']['name']); $i++) {
                list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES["uploaded_files"]['tmp_name'][$i]);

                if ($_FILES['uploaded_files']['type'][$i] == "image/png"
                    || $_FILES['uploaded_files']['type'][$i] == "image/jpeg"
                    || $_FILES['uploaded_files']['type'][$i] == "image/gif"
                ) {
                    $imgPath = "../files/img/galleries/" . $gallery_name . "/" . $_FILES['uploaded_files']['name'][$i];
                    $thumbPath = "../files/img/galleries/" . $gallery_name . "/thumbs/" . $_FILES['uploaded_files']['name'][$i];

                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_files']['tmp_name'][$i], strtolower($imgPath));

                    $filehandler->makeThumbnails($imgPath, $thumbPath, 300, 215);
                }

            }
            header('location: '.MAINPATH.'/galleri/'.$gallery_name.'?billeder_uploadet');
```

And the errors i am getting, when trying to upload some files (images) on the server is:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(../files/img/galleries/test/1383204_10200900060289437_410542691_n.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/xn--cstanlg-rxa.dk/public_html/web/templates/formReceiverPost.php on line 35
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phptu17Hf' to '../files/img/galleries/test/1383204_10200900060289437_410542691_n.jpg' in /var/www/xn--cstanlg-rxa.dk/public_html/web/templates/formReceiverPost.php on line 35
>
> Warning: getimagesize(../files/img/galleries/Test/1383204_10200900060289437_410542691_n.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/xn--cstanlg-rxa.dk/public_html/lib/class/FileHandler.php on line 158
>
> Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/xn--cstanlg-rxa.dk/public_html/lib/class/FileHandler.php on line 159
>
> Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/xn--cstanlg-rxa.dk/public_html/lib/class/FileHandler.php on line 159
>
> Warning: imagecreatetruecolor() [function.imagecreatetruecolor]: Invalid image dimensions in /var/www/xn--cstanlg-rxa.dk/public_html/lib/class/FileHandler.php on line 162

When I try to upload 0 files to the server it gives me this error:

> Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in /var/www/xn--cstanlg-rxa.dk/public_html/web/templates/formReceiverPost.php on line 26

Which I don't think makes sense, as I am checking if any files has been sent through..

I thought it might have something to do with permissions on the server, but all the relevant folders is set to '755'.

I hope someone might know what the problem could be.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are both `test` and `Test` if your paths (in the 3 first warnings). Pick one and stick with it. Linux is case-sensitive for paths and folder/file names. Windows is not.

Comment: Just because `$_FILES['uploaded_files']` exists, doesn't mean there wasn't any error. Check for errors.

Comment: Thanks @D4V1D! That was it. If you post an answer I'll accept it. And @Charlotte Dunois, thanks also. I will try checking for errors instead. I just read that it could be done like I was doing it in my question, but apparently that wasn't the case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check carefully your errors.

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(../files/img/galleries/**test**/1383204_10200900060289437_410542691_n.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/xn--cstanlg-rxa.dk/public_html/web/templates/formReceiverPost.php on line 35
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phptu17Hf' to '../files/img/galleries/**test**/1383204_10200900060289437_410542691_n.jpg' in /var/www/xn--cstanlg-rxa.dk/public_html/web/templates/formReceiverPost.php on line 35
>
> Warning: getimagesize(../files/img/galleries/**Test**/1383204_10200900060289437_410542691_n.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/xn--cstanlg-rxa.dk/public_html/lib/class/FileHandler.php on line 158

You have both `test` and `Test` in your paths.

Remember that Linux is case-sensitive for file and folder names. Windows is not. That might explain why it worked on your dev environment and why it didn't anymore on your prod server.

So pick either one of them and stick with it (I wouldn't recommend to use uppercase characters in your paths though).